# Angular 17 build failing when API routes are defined in the server.ts file

Tags: angular

I've upgraded to Angular 17 and change my builder to `@angular-devkit/build-angular:application` as it is the new recommended way to build angular SSR apps.

Before that update, I would run `npm run build` and it would build both the server and browser app perfectly fine (no pre-rendering).

And after starting the server with `node ./dist/[app-name]/server/index.js`, it would render each view perfectly fine as I hit the different URLs of the app.

Now, it tried to pre-render the browser app, but without running the angular server which contains API routes that sort of proxy's to my actual API (different project), thus failing.

Questions:

1. Is there a way to prevent the pre-rendering phase?
2. Or, is there a way that the server runs before the pre-render phase?
3. Is there something I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    "server": "src/main.server.ts",
              "prerender": false,
              "ssr": false
```

This is how you can disable ssr and prerendering in you angular.json

Comment: And it was staring in my face this whole time **face palm**. Thanks!